# Jasper report stacked bar chart: issues

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am using stacked bar chart generated by jasper report(using jfree charts),I have below issues

1. Value is not visible if bar chart width is very less,(attached image is 1.png) [image]
2. I need the fixed colors for fixed values.(Attached image is 2.png)[image] For example Rejected must be red,Open-Yellow,Approved and not fulfilled-Orange,approved and fulfilled - Green.
   For this I am using series color,But it will gives correct color only when all sections(Rejected,Open,approved and not fulfilled,approved and fulfilled) are available,If any of the section is mission,the color scheme will get change(Reason is it will take the colours based on alphabetic order).
   But I want strict color scheme irrespective of availability of sections.
   I have tried different google searched/bar chart customizers ,but not able to achieve.
   Please post your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Image after @Vikki888 solution

[image]

Comment: For 2, how are you fetching the data?

Comment: @Viki888, I am getting data from mysql db,I have a query which will return the status and the count.

Answer (score 0):

For problem 2, you can try following below steps,

Order the colors in chart setting as below,

```
i) Red

ii) Yellow

iii) Orange

iv) Green
```

Say below is your query

```
Select status, count
from table1
```

Just modify the query to below format,

```
SELECT 
    t1.status, 
    CASE WHEN t2.status IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t2.count END as count
FROM 
    (SELECT 'Rejected' status, 1 as status_order
    UNION SELECT 'Open', 2
    UNION SELECT 'Approved and not fulfilled', 3
    UNION SELECT 'Approved and Fulfilled', 4) t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (Select status, count
    from table1) t2 
    ON t1.status = t2.status
ORDER BY t1.status_order ASC;
```

This will solve problem 2.

For problem 1, check whether you have **any alignment properties for plotoptions**, if so modify it to `center` or `remove that option` and test it.

Comment: @Vikki888,thanks for comment,Can you please tell me how can I define the mapping for Red-1,Yellow-2,Orange-3,Green-4. As of now I am using series in iReport where I am defining the color order.                                     Another issue is the query is always returning (status , count)(Rejected 0),In table1 I dont have the count as column I am doing count(*) as count

Comment: You do not need to define any mapping. The order in which the colors are defined in properties will automatically map with the series defined. And `Select status, count from table1` query is just a sample query. You have to replace your query, which you have right now, instead of it.

Comment: @Vikki888,thanks for comment,I did the changes ,But the colors are still not coming as required,The problem is if any of the status is missing the color for that status will be taken by next(in status order) as we are defining the count to 0 in case of missing status,But it doesn't use any color if count is 0.I have attached the image in question

Comment: Kindly update your question with the color properties design.